# SQL: Pull previous day's activity (include weekend on Mondays)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to return data from the previous day, except for on Monday I want to return data from the previous 3 days. The below seems logical to me, though I'm getting the error of `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Any idea what I'm missing?

*Dates stored in datetime hence the `CONVERT` functions.

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()) IN ('1')
    THEN (CONVERT(DATE,EV.EVENT_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-3,GETDATE()))) 
    ELSE (CONVERT(DATE,EV.EVENT_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE()))) 
    END
```

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. Aside: It's a bit peculiar to get an `int` from `DatePart` and check to see if it is in a list of one string value (`'1'`) rather than an `int` value (`1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not support boolean expressions like this.

You can express this without the `case`, which is generally preferable:

```
WHERE ( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 1 AND CONVERT(DATE, EV.EVENT_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()))
      ) OR
      ( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) <> 1 AND CONVERT(DATE, EV.EVENT_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
      )
```

EDIT:

If you want the weekend dates, then use inequalities.  Assuming `event_date`s are not in the future:

You'll notice that I spelled out the date parts.  I find this a better practice than trying to remember/figure out what a particular abbreviation might mean.

```
WHERE ( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 1 AND CONVERT(DATE, EV.EVENT_DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()))
      ) OR
      ( DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) <> 1 AND CONVERT(DATE, EV.EVENT_DATE) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
      )
```

Comment: Note that this has a dependency on the `DATEFIRST` setting.

Comment: Although this is technically fixing the issues in the OPs SQL, it doesn't actually do what they asked.  They wanted to return data from the previous 3 days on a Monday, but this will only return data from 3 days ago on a Monday.  Just needs a `=` changing to a `<=`?